# How can you change the precision of the percentage field in tqdm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I have a very large iterable which means a lot of iterations must pass before the bar updates by 1%. It populates a sqlite database from legacy excel sheets.

Minimum reproducible example is something like this.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm, trange
import time

percentage = 0
total = 157834

l_bar = '{desc}: {percentage:.3f}%|'
r_bar = '| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}, ' '{rate_fmt}{postfix}]'
format = '{l_bar}{bar}{r_bar}'
for row in tqdm(range(2, total), ncols=100, bar_format=format):
    percentage = row/total * 100
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

In this example I have left all these strings as their default values except for trying to modify the percentage field in l_bar in an attempt to get decimals of a percent to print. And I haven't been able to find a default definition of `bar` anywhere in the docs so this implementation causes the loading bar to stop working.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm):

> bar_format : str, optional
> Specify a custom bar string formatting. May impact performance. [default: '{l_bar}{bar}{r_bar}'], where l_bar='{desc}: {percentage:3.0f}%|' and r_bar='| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}, ' '{rate_fmt}{postfix}]' Possible vars: l_bar, bar, r_bar, n, n_fmt, total, total_fmt, percentage, elapsed, elapsed_s, ncols, nrows, desc, unit, rate, rate_fmt, rate_noinv, rate_noinv_fmt, rate_inv, rate_inv_fmt, postfix, unit_divisor, remaining, remaining_s, eta. Note that a trailing ": " is automatically removed after {desc} if the latter is empty.

However I try it seems to come out as a flat 0% and then a jump to 1% every time.

How am I misunderstanding the documentation here?

Comment: That's not a minimal reproducible example. It fails with `NameError: name 'desc' is not defined`.

Comment: @user2357112 edited. Was playing about with it while writing the question and left an f string in that shouldn't have been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar_format` doesn't work like that - it's not going to look up values of `l_bar` or `r_bar` that you define in your own code. All format specifiers will be filled in with values provided on tqdm's end.

Use a single layer of formatting, based on the variables tqdm provides:

```
for row in tqdm(whatever, bar_format='{desc}: {percentage:3.2f}%|{bar}{r_bar}'):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I was having trouble understanding the documentation there. I also had the issue like the others in the other thread of percentage not appearing as valid key in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way,

```
from tqdm import tqdm, trange
import time

total = 1000

class TqdmExtraFormat(tqdm):
    @property
    def format_dict(self):
        d = super(TqdmExtraFormat, self).format_dict
        decimalpercentage = '{:.2f}'.format(d["rate"]/100) if d["rate"] else '?'
        d.update(percentage = decimalpercentage)
        return d

b= '{percentage}%|{bar}{r_bar}'
for i in TqdmExtraFormat(range(2, total), bar_format=b):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Because in the documentation, eventhough percentage is listed as a variable, I'm not able to find the key in the dictionary. Therefore, we shall utilize rate divided by 100 instead. One thing missing is I can't get the decimals to change to two places even after specifying .2f format. Maybe you could find out more on that. Otherwise, it works like what you requested.

Output:
[image]

Comment: "Because in the documentation, they don't list any variables to be used for percentage" - what do you mean? It looks like the variable for percentage is `percentage`. It's in the list between `total_fmt` and `elapsed`.

Comment: Of course, that might not work so well with you stomping that name with your own `percentage`.

Comment: in the dictionary, I'm not able to find the "percentage" key, even though it's listed in the documentation. I've edited the answer to state that point.

Comment: Huh. Weird. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/v4.64.1/tqdm/std.py), `self.format_dict` is missing a lot of stuff available to `bar_format`. The code that handles progress bar formatting builds a second `format_dict` with a whole bunch of stuff that isn't in `self.format_dict`.

Comment: `percentage` *is* available for use in `bar_format`, though. In fact, the reason you couldn't control the decimal places is because the tqdm-standard `percentage` is overriding the `percentage` you tried to define.

Comment: so, are you saying that that's the best we could do? since the channel for formatting is incomplete. Or do you have a better suggestion? Asking because I'm trying to learn too.

Comment: Just setting a `bar_format` that uses the provided `percentage` should work: `bar_format='{desc}: {percentage:3.2f}%|{bar}{r_bar}'`

Comment: not should but yes it works. you may post an answer below. I'll just leave mine for discussion sake. also, if I input 3.2f into mine, it works as well. but what's the difference between 3.2f and .2f? 3.2f is like print with at least 3 wide but with two decimal places, whereas .2f is rounding of decimal to two places. hmm both should generate the same output, shouldn't they?